# How to Dynamically Generate String Validation?

Tags: php, regex, webforms, validation

Does anyone know of a library (preferably php) or algorithm for auto-generating regex's from some common descriptions?

For example, have a form with the possible options of:

```
 - Length (=x, between x & y, etc)
  - Starts with
  - Ends with
  - Character(s) x(yz) at index i
  - Specify one or more alternative behavior based on the above
  - And so on..
```

The idea is that for certain data entities in a system, you'll be able to go to a form and set this criteria for a data field. Afterward, any time that data field for that type of data entity is entered, it will be validated against the regex.

This seems like it could grow into a complex problem though, so I'm not expecting anyone to solve it as a whole. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: It's especially complicate to find a library for the *"And so on..."* point. As long as you don't specifically write what you're looking for it's hard to answer at all.

Answer (score 2):

Would simple globs be enough? For globs it's just a matter of replacing * with .* and adding ^ and $. Or may be Excel-style patterns? It should not be too hard to write a regexp generator for simple rules like this...

My point is, adjust your requirements to simplify the code, and then may be add more features as needed.

Comment: Globs should be, but I didn't really want to have to write my own re code generator and some of the patters may be fairly complex. For your 2nd point, I wish I could simplify, but the validation is on input from many different entities who don't agree on universal formats; I'd like to support each.